# why lua kv pairs is sequence when key is table

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
local a = {d = 1}
local b = {d = 2}
local test = {}

test[b] = true
test[a] = true

newtest = {
  d = 1,
  c = 2
}
for i in ipairs(test) do
  print(i.d)
end

for k, v in pairs(newtest) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

**so why the print of test is in order but the newtest is not every time?

Comment: The first loop never does anything. `test` has no array elements, so `ipairs` returns an empty iterator.

Comment: `pairs` doesn't iterate in order

Answer (score 2):

From the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 6.1 Basic Functions: ipairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs)

> **ipairs (t)** Returns three values (an iterator function, the table t, and 0) so that the construction
>
> `for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end`
>
> will iterate over the key–value pairs `(1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ...,` up to
> the first nil value.

So `ipairs` won't work for test as `test` is not a sequence starting at index 1. It only has two keys which are tables.